# How to update state conditionally in Stateless Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two components. MyButton and MyLabel component. I created 3 MyButton Compoents and 3 MyLabel Components. Each button has a different increment value. When you click on a button , the respective label should be updated not all the labels. At present all the labels are updating.

```
function MyButton(props) {
  const onclick = () => {
    props.onNumberIncrement(props.toBeIncremented);
  };
  return <button onClick={onclick}>+{props.toBeIncremented}</button>;
}

const MyLabel = function(props) {
  return <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{props.counter}</label>;
};

function App(props) {
  const [counter, mySetCounter] = React.useState(0);

  const handleClick = (incrementValue) => {
    mySetCounter(counter + incrementValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton
        counter={counter}
        onNumberIncrement={handleClick}
        toBeIncremented={5}
      />
      <MyButton
        counter={counter}
        onNumberIncrement={handleClick}
        toBeIncremented={10}
      />
      <MyButton
        counter={counter}
        onNumberIncrement={handleClick}
        toBeIncremented={15}
      />
      <br />
      <MyLabel counter={counter} />
      <MyLabel counter={counter} />
      <MyLabel counter={counter} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

jsfiddle:
[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/tony1947/7zbu0ygn/1/)

Comment: if you want individual values for each Button/Label, you will need to create three different state values

Comment: You're passing the same state and handler to all three buttons so when one increment it will update all three

Comment: Yes, my code is wrong, Can you pls correct my code and paste

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Can you pls correct my code and paste it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution using a single state variable :

```
function App(props) {
      const [appState, setAppState] = React.useState([
       {value: 0, incrementValue: 5},
       {value: 0, incrementValue: 10},
       {value: 0, incrementValue: 15}
      ]);

      const handleClick = clickedIndex => () => {
        setAppState(
          appState.map((item, index) => clickedIndex !== index ? 
            item : ({...item, value: item.value + item.incrementValue})
          ) 
        );
      };

      return (
        <div>
         {
           appState.map(({value, incrementValue}, index) => (
            <MyButton
              key={index}
              counter={value}
              onNumberIncrement={handleClick(index)}
              toBeIncremented={incrementValue}
            />
           ));
          }
          <br />
          {
            appState.map(
              ({value}, index) => <MyLabel key={index} counter={value} />
            );
          }
         </div>
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a generator of button/label pairs with their local state and step. Generate the buttons and labels, and render them:

```js
const useGenerateButtonAndLabel = step => {
  const [counter, mySetCounter] = React.useState(0);
  
  const onclick = React.useCallback(
    () => mySetCounter(counter + step), 
    [step, counter]
  );

  return [
    <button onClick={onclick}>+{step}</button>,
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{counter}</label>
  ];
};

function App(props) {
  const [button1, label1] = useGenerateButtonAndLabel(5);
  const [button2, label2] = useGenerateButtonAndLabel(10);
  const [button3, label3] = useGenerateButtonAndLabel(15);

  return (
    <div>
      {button1}
      {button2}
      {button3}
      <br />
      {label1}
      {label2}
      {label3}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

If you also need a total, each generated pair can also return it's current `counter`, and you can sum them in the parent. In this example, I also automate the items creation/rendering with `Array.from()`, map, and reduce.

```js
const useGenerateButtonAndLabel = step => {
  const [counter, mySetCounter] = React.useState(0);
  
  const onclick = React.useCallback(
    () => mySetCounter(counter + step), 
    [step, counter]
  );
  
  // step is used here is a key, but if step is not unique, it will fail. You might want to generate a UUID here
  return [
    <button key={step} onClick={onclick}>+{step}</button>,
    <label key={step}>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{counter}</label>,
    counter
  ];
};

const sum = items => items.reduce((r, [,, counter]) => r + counter, 0);

function App(props) {
  const items = Array.from({ length: 5 }, 
    (_, i) => useGenerateButtonAndLabel(5 * (i + 1))
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(([button]) => button)}
      <br />
      {items.map(([, label]) => label)}
      
      <div>Total: {sum(items)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: as `generateButtonAndLabel` is a custom Hooks, it should begin by `use`, otherwise the linter will not detect it

Comment: I'm not sure it's a hook. It's a generator of react components with a hook.

Comment: it use `React.useState`, if you call `generateButtonAndLabel` inside a condition, the linter will not detect that you are doing a mistake

Comment: Updated. Still conceptually weird naming in this case.

Comment: @OriDrori, thank you for your code. What exactly is the difference between Christopher Ngo's code and your code, except the automation? Can you pls let me know..Anything optimised or something.. just I got a doubt in mind.. thank you

Comment: Mainly the DRYness, and automation. Except for that, it's the same idea.